# Flask CORS: how could I receive an 'Authorization' header?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, cors, flask-cors

I have a front-end application on Vue.js and a back-end application on Flask/Python.

I'm trying to send to the back-end a request with an 'Authorization' header, however this header is not arriving on my back-end.

I've already tried to make available this header in the CORS function, but without success.

Would anyone know how I could fix it?

I send below the front-end and back-end code.

Thank you in advance.

**Vue.js code**

```
var authorization = ...

axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_URL + 'ms3/sign_in', 
  {
    params: {
    }
  }, {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      'Authorization': authorization
    }
  }).then(response => {
    localStorage.setItem('ms3_user_token', response.headers.authorization)
  }).catch(error => {
    self.errorSignIn = error
    self.erroredSignIn = true
  }).finally(() => {
    self.loading = false
  })
```

**Flask Code:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

...

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins='*', 
     headers=['Content-Type', 'Authorization'], 
     expose_headers='Authorization')

...

@app.route("/ms3/sign_in", methods = ["POST", "OPTIONS"])
def ms3_sign_in(): 
    # the header does not exist
    auth_header = request.headers.get("Authorization")

    if auth_header is None or not auth_header.startswith('Basic '):
        return jsonify({ "message": "Invalid 'Authorization' header" }), 401

    username, password = ...

    encoded_jwt_token = auth_login(username, password)

    resp = Response("Returned Token")
    resp.headers['Authorization'] = encoded_jwt_token

    return resp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank to Allan from Python Brasil group that helped me.

It was needed to add "'Content-Type': 'application/json'" in my request on Vue.js application.

I send below the updated code for future help:

**Vue.js code**

```
var authorization = ...

axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_URL + 'ms3/sign_in', 
  {
    params: {
    }
  }, {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',  // <-- here
      'Authorization': authorization
    }
  }).then(response => {
    localStorage.setItem('ms3_user_token', response.headers.authorization)
  }).catch(error => {
    self.errorSignIn = error
    self.erroredSignIn = true
  }).finally(() => {
    self.loading = false
  })
```